# Kotlin Advanced Typing: abstract classes, interfaces to reduce boilerplate converting Room classes to other classes

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have several Room entities (`WEntity`) and corresponding non-Room models (`WModel`).

The Room entities are inner joined to create a hierarchy (`WHierarchy`) (grandparent -> list(parent) -> list(children) -> ...).

I need to be able to convert entities to their corresponding models, and hierarchies to their corresponding models. (E.g., `FooModel` has `FooEntity` data plus a list of `BarModels` (mapped from `BarEntity`'s).

Currently I represent this hierarchy as `FooHierarchy(val parent: FooEntity, val children: List<BarEntity>)`, for example.

Here are my initial interfaces describing what they *ought to* do as best I can:

```
interface WModel

interface WEntity<T: WModel> {
    fun toModel(): T
}

abstract class WHierarchy<Parent: WEntity<ParentModel>, Child: WEntity<ChildModel>, ParentModel: WModel, ChildModel: WModel> {
    abstract val parent: Parent
    abstract val children: List<Child>
    fun toModel(): ParentModel {
        return when(this) {
            is WOHierarchy -> parent.toModel().copy(lgs=children.map { it.toModel() })
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("bork bork bork")
        }
    }
}
```

Here are sample entities:

```
data class WOEntity(val id: Int): WEntity<WO> {
    override fun toModel(): WO {
        return WO(id=id, lgs=emptyList())
    }
}

data class LGEntity(val id: Int): WEntity<LG> {
    override fun toModel(): LG {
        return LG(id=id)
    }
}
```

and their corresponding models:

```
data class WO(val id: Int, val lgs: List<LG>): WModel
data class LG(val id: Int): WModel
```

And the hierarchy:

```
data class WOHierarchy(override val parent: WOEntity, override val children: List<LGEntity>): WHierarchy<WOEntity, LGEntity, WO, LG>()
```

**My issue I run into is my abstract class `WHierarchy`. Current implementation marks**

`parent.toModel().copy(lgs=children.map { it.toModel() })`

**and says "Type Mismatch: Required: ParentModel. Found: WO."**

I'm confused: WO implements ParentModel! How do I fix this? SHouldn't the compiler be able to tell that WO implements ParentModel and thus I'm returning a ParentModel like I'm supposed to?

This is all an attempt to abstract away the `Hierarchy`'s `toModel()` (and a companion object's `fromModel()` eventually), which is pretty boilerplatey because I actually have four or five Hierarchy-implementing classes in the exact same way, same keywords, just different return class (hence the WModel interface that otherwise does nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after casting is `WOHierarchy -> parent.toModel()` 
the compiler knows that the parent.toModel() function returns `WO` and that Parent type is `WOEntity`.
and you telling him the return type inside the abstract class model function is `Parent` you need to change in the abstract class

```
fun toModel(): WModel
```

-

```
abstract class WHierarchy<Parent : WEntity<ParentModel>, Child : WEntity<ChildModel>, ParentModel : WModel, ChildModel : WModel> {
    abstract val parent: Parent
    abstract val children: List<Child>
    fun toModel(): WModel {
        return when (this) {
            is WOHierarchy -> parent.toModel().copy(lgs = children.map { it.toModel() })
            else -> throw IllegalStateException("bork bork bork")
        }
    }
}
```